# Hide a parameter from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have successfully removed the parameters from the URL with this (htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=2
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/contact-us? [R=301,L]
```

However in the root directory there's a folder called "mobile", which contains the same pages as the root directory except they are designed for mobile devices, and I need to remove the parameters from there aswell. Now mobile pages redirect to non-mobile pages because they have the same parameters:

```
//non-mobile
http://www.website.com/index.html?id=1
//mobile
http://www.website.com/mobile/index.html?id=1
```

I obviously need them to redirect to the "mobile" folder, but I can't figure out how to do it.

By the way, if anyone is wondering why there is an html extension, it's because I copied a website with a program called HTTrack. It saves pages as index.html, index4352.html etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a separate .htaccess file in the mobile folder as well, in which you redirect to the mobile index.html.